# Add method in Entity not reached

Tags: symfony, doctrine, sonata-admin

I need to bugfix a Symfony3 project with Sonata Admin & Doctrine.

I got a field list, with all textures saved in base
[image: Texture view]

The problem is in the "addTexture" method, the previous developer did :

```
public function addTexture(\AppBundle\Entity\Texture $texture)
{
    if (count($this->textures[]) < 26)
        $this->textures[] = $texture;
    return $this;
}
```

And we can add more than 25 textures : that's my bug.

So I added a dump($this->textures); exit; and nothing happen, the app never reach this. While in other entities, the "add" method is reached.

**EDIT** :

Seems like it's my Doctrine2 ArrayCollection that never fire all my addXXX methods. But it saving my collections on database, and i don't know why.

**EDIT 2** :

I found where the list is declared :

```
        ->add('colors','sonata_type_model', [
            'multiple' => true,
            'expanded' => false,
            'property' => 'Name'
        ])
```

Is there a way to add a limit or maximum item ? Then I won't need to update the Entity if it's UI restricted.

Comment: I suggest you to [read what is allowed and what is not on SO.](https://stackoverflow.com/help) This kind of question is not allowed. Said that, looking at your code, you should remove the if condition or update to new limit value.

Comment: The problem is the "if" is not even reached. When I delete the whole method code and only put a var_dump & exit, the code is running normally.

Comment: where did `addTexure` method call from?

Comment: addTexture got only 1 reference on my project, and it's the method definition. So that's why it's not called. But for exemple I got an Entity Color. And addGreen, addRed, addBlue. They are never called in the view (like addTexture) but on the Form when I create new entity or update, the method are called.

Comment: count($this->textures[]), why the [] ?

Comment: Not my code, but yeah the [] is a mistake. But it's not my bug, even without it change nothing since this code is not called.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use ArrayCollection methods (let's say that we work on Color Entity):

```
public function addTexture(\AppBundle\Entity\Texture $texture)
{
    if ($this->textures->count() < 26) {
        $this->textures->add($texture);
        $texture->setColor($this); //Add this if you have bidirectional mapping
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is the code is never called, the add method never fired (but i don't know why, because textures are added in database). So I did a hack on preUpdate until I find why add and remove method are never fired.

Comment: Then I think he probably used the method from the other side, i mean he add texture to the Color class by setColor(Color $color) on the Texture entity, so check the TexturesController or something like that.